# Automatically login to Sharepoint with Network credentails

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to get a list of all sites available to the user, from a SharePoint 2013 server. Is there a way to authenticate with the SharePoint server, using network credentials?

Examples I see seem to pass a username, password and domain.

eg:

```
string _siteURL = "https://intranet.co.uk";

        NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "https://intranet");

        ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(_siteURL);

        _clientContext.Credentials = _myCredentials;
```

Is there a way to NOT request a username/password from the user and get the list of sites available to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Domain in Network Credentials is not your website URL domain (https://sdbdbs), but your credentials domain (domain\username) . Figure out your domain name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code running from a console application?
It should use following to use current user's credentials

```
 _clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```